# Adding lines into chart control

Tags: asp.net, microsoft-chart-controls

I am struggling with SqlDataReader and ChartControl. I have added one line without any problem, but i want to add multiple of them and can't do that at all altought I was searching for that all day long.

What I have is table with some names of columns id, date, value1, value2, value3. I am getting them using SqlDataReader.

```
SqlConnection con4 = new
SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["przychodniaConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);

string cmdStr4 = "select badCisData, badCisSkurczowe, badCisRozkurczowe, badCisPuls from badanieCis where pacID='" +
Label3.Text + "' ORDER BY badCisData ASC";

SqlCommand getResults = new SqlCommand(cmdStr4, con4);

con4.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = getResults.ExecuteReader();
```

Then I am making my chart like that:

> Chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(reader, "badCisData",
>   reader, "badCisPuls");
>   Chart2.Series["Series2"].Points.DataBindXY(reader, "badCisData",
>   reader, "badCisSkurczowe");

And I have error on Series2. I would like to put date on x axis and on y axis (value1, value2 etc.)

Comment: Did u add second Series with name="Series2" to the Chart before using it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection con4 = new
SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["przychodniaConnectionString1"].ConnectionString))
{

    string cmdStr4 = "select badCisData, badCisSkurczowe, badCisRozkurczowe, badCisPuls from badanieCis where pacID='" +
    Label3.Text + "' ORDER BY badCisData ASC";

    using (SqlCommand getResults = new SqlCommand(cmdStr4, con4))
    {

        con4.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = getResults.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                //Your code like reader["Column Name"]
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I put inside if - Chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(reader, "badCisData", reader, "badCisPuls"); but when I put another one, still the same error

Comment: You mean like that:
string data = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("badCisData"));
                                string CisSkurczowe = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("badCisSkurczowe"));
                                string CisRozkurczowe = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("badCisRozkurczowe"));
                                string CisPuls = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("badCisPuls"));

And how to generate chart from that?

Comment: Changed for proper types, but still dont know where to put Chart executing function and how should it looks

Comment: what parameters do DataBindXY have ?

Comment: I am trying to do like that:
 string cisData = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("badCisData")).ToString("dd MMM yyyy"); 
Chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(reader, "cisData", reader, "CisSkurczoweString"); 
                                int CisSkurczowe = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("badCisSkurczowe"));
                                string CisSkurczoweString = CisSkurczowe.ToString();

Chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(reader, "cisData", reader, "CisSkurczoweString");

Comment: What type of parameters do the DataBindXY have? While fetching the results from database are you getting DBNull values ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8896/discussion-between-pankaj-garg-and-dargod)